# retrieving basic value from website HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use HtmlAgilityPack with c# to go to a simple website https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/pewdiepie and read the number of subscribers. I can't seem to work it out or find anything useful on the internet please help I don't want to read tables or anything just one simple value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = web.Load("https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/pewdiepie");
        HtmlNode thingy = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("not sure how to find xpath");

        Console.WriteLine(thingy);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to use HAP, great. Can you share *how* you are using it and where you are stuck?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing hi, i have tried countless things and this is just at a save                                                                                                      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc = web.Load("https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/pewdiepie");
            HtmlNode thingy = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("not sure how to find xpath");

            Console.WriteLine(thingy);
            Console.Read();
        }

Comment: Are you familiar with JS `querySelector`? Install `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack` NuGet package additionally. There will be `HtmlNode.QuerySelector()` available that accepts JS query syntax.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find the XPath is in Chrome (other browsers may have identical features):

- right-click on the value you want in the page, choose "inspect" - this opens the dev-tools on that element
- right-click that HTML-element, choose "Copy" > "Copy as XPath"

This puts the following on the clipboard:

```
//*[@id="YouTubeUserTopInfoBlock"]/div[3]/span[2]
```

Note that this may not be the most efficient XPath. Also note that some sites load data through javascript, which will not be executed by HAP.

Explanation of that XPath:

- get any element with "id" equal to "YouTubeUserTopInfoBlock"
- directly below that, get the third `<div>` element
- directly below that, get the second `<span>` element

Then you still need to get the InnerText of that selected node to get the "106M" value.